# Bootstrap: Have centered block and right block on same row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've never really gotten the hang of Bootstrap, but now I really need it and I after searching around I can't get it to work as I want it to.

What I need is quite simple. Two div's were one is centered on the screen and one is on the far right. For the centered div I got it to work with center-block, but then everything after is placed on a new line. Code:

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="center-block col-md-4" style={{ float: 'none' }}>Logo</div>
  <div className="col-md-4">Some links</div>
</div>
```

If I map out the whole row with three div's and col-md-4 I get it one the same line, but I really want to avoid having just an empty div.

But if I use the last method I still got the problem with the div far right. The best I can get is by applying text-xs-right to the right div, but it's still not far enough for what I need. Code:

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-md-4" />
  <div className="col-md-4">Logo</div>
  <div className="col-md-4 text-xs-right">Some links</div>
</div>
```

How I want it to look:

```
_______________________________
|          Logo          Links |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|______________________________|
```

Edit: After trying it in bootply I see that it might be a problem with my setup as it looks just as how I want it there.

Edit 2: Looks like I'm using bootstrap 4 and that's why it didn't work. Sorry!

Edit 3: I'm using jsx, therefore I need className. It's just the same as class in normal HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work in Bootstrap 4. Don't forget to use `class=`, instead of `className=`:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 text-center">Logo</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-right">Some links</div>
 </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/8gGRrwsyiL

Answer (score 0):

Change className to class

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Logo Here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need className since I'm using jsx, and those classes is not what I'm after since the logo isn't centered on the screen and the second class is not far right at all (although that might be jsx's fault since pull-right doesn't work at all).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">Logo</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">Some links</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 text-center">Logo</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-right">Some links</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working, sorry.

But after testing it out in a playground it might simply be because of my jsx setup as your code looked perfect in the simulator.